# Primefaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT filterBy new syntax issue

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In Primefaces 4.0, the syntax for the filterBy attribute has changed. In the demo code they list the 3.x and the 4.x syntax. Basically it boils down to changing :

```
<p:column filterBy="#{var.property}"> ...
```

to:

```
<p:column filterBy="property"> ...
```

That's all great, however we use a Map in the backing bean, which used to work really well in 3.5:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{utilityBean.vendorMap[var.id]}"> ...
```

My question is how do I accomplish the same thing with the new syntax ?

Edit (9/9/2013):

The Map in question returns the vendor's name, given the database ID:

```
private Map<BigInteger, String> vendorMap;
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but does your `#{utilityBean.vendorMap[var.id]}` return the string `"property"`? That should theoretically just work fine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved in Primefaces 5.0. You can now use the old and new syntax.